# Failed to initialize a glossary. 404 Glossary not found - While running the Google translation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use Google translation with glossary. The Glossary is created, I can see it in activity dashboard:

[image]

But when I try to get_glossary (just a simple script from google) server responce.

```
name = client.glossary_path( project_id, "us-central1", glossary_id)
print(name)
response = client.get_glossary(name)
```

-------- output:

```
NotFound: 404 Glossary not found.
```

Trying use list_glossaries, but it return noting. Can't figured out where mistake is?

Comment: Just a reminder to mask your project ID and email so these information are not exposed to public.

Answer (score 0):

Based from your screenshot you were able to create the glossary. Another way to check glossary if it is existing is to use the **Long Running Operation ID** (Underlined in **Red**.)

[image]

Send a request to GET the status of the operation. Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/long-running-operation) for a better explanation on using long running operations.

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/your-project-id-here/locations/us-central1/operations/your-opperation-id-here
```

It will return this response that contains the status of your operation. Compare the returned "name" versus the returned "name" in your code `name = client.glossary_path( project_id, "us-central1", glossary_id)` and check if there are just wrong parameters.

[image]

Also just a note, the proper way to use [client.get_glossary](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/translate_v3/services.html#google.cloud.translate_v3.services.translation_service.TranslationServiceClient.get_glossary) is to pass a request object.

```
name = client.glossary_path( project_id, "us-central1", glossary_id)
print(name) # projects/your-project-id/locations/us-central1/glossaries/your-glossary-id
request = {"name" : name}
response = client.get_glossary(request)  # pass the request object
```